# Can't connect to MySQL server on localhost (10060)

Tags: windows, mysql

i have install the "mysql-6.0.11-alpha-win32" setup in windows 7 . then try to connect to the mysql but it takes long time to connect to the mysql server then show the error message like

```
--------------------------- 
SQLyog - Free MySQL GUI 
--------------------------- 
Error No. 2003 
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10060) 
--------------------------- 
OK Help 
---------------------------
```

any one have idea about this error no. 2003 then help me.... 
thanks in advance... .

Answer (score 4):

Read this FAQ: http://webyog.com/faq/content/23/15/en/error-no-2003-can_t-connect.html Also this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

Note that this is a *connection* error and not an *authentication* error (ie: not because user or password is wrong).

First you should check for firewall issues and settings in server configurations like 'skip_networking' and 'bind_address'.

Comment: in the first reference of the link mentioned as comment the "skip-networking" in my.cnf file but in my installation .cnf file "skip-networking" setting not found

Answer (score 1):

This is the firewall issue and you need to update the firewall present in the system. Normally Microsoft windows firewall restricts the system to access the permission of the server and it doesn’t allow connecting the server. Then for solving this kind of issue normally we need to update this firewall. The updated version of the firewall will provide this facility to connect the MYSQL Server to the system. Then you can able to run SQL on your system.

Comment: how to update the firewall

Comment: in my system windows firewall is turn off

Comment: Try to update the firewall and try again. if u still got the error msg, try reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `mysqlid.exe` into your windows firewall settings to access your server remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Update the windows hosts file. Make sure that your windows host file has following line

```
// if not, add at the end
// location: c://windows/system32/drivers/etc.host.file (open with notepad)
// (# xxxxxx is comment and hence do not start with it)

127.0.0.1 localhost
```